# CSS equal number of columns on each row for responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, grid

I am working on a control panel that has 36 buttons. It is possible to add more buttons in the future, but the total number will always be even. I want the buttons to have the same width and height and to resize in the container when the user resizes the browser window.

On big screens there will be one row like this:
[image]

On laptop will be like this:
[image]

On tablet or smaller screens will be like this:
[image]

I have fixed with media queries for specific screens but problems happen if the user resizes the window (wants to see multiple windows at the same time). It is difficult to set tens of media queries. I am looking for a more general solution.

This is what I **do not** want to see on my site:
[image]
[image]

This is the snippet I am working on. I have tried both flex and grid approaches, but with no success.

```js
   insertButtons("flex-container")
            insertButtons("grid-container")

            function insertButtons(containerId) {
                let container = document.getElementById(containerId)
                let number = 36
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                    let button = document.createElement("button")
                    button.innerHTML = i+1
                    if (containerId == "flex-container") {
                        button.classList.add("element-button")
                    }
                    container.appendChild(button)
                }
            }
```

```css
.container {
                background: black;
                position: relative;
                margin-top: 20px;
                width: 96vw;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, 0);
                padding: 5pt;
            }
            
            #flex-container { 
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap; 
            }

            #grid-container { 
                padding: 5pt;
                background: black;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(32pt, 1fr));
                grid-auto-rows: 30pt;
                grid-gap: 3pt; 
            }

            .element-button {
                margin: 2pt;
                padding: 2pt;
                flex-grow: 1;
                height: 30pt;
                min-width: 20pt;;
            } 

            button {
                border-radius: 3pt;
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }
```

```html
   <h1 align="center">Flex</h1>
       <div id="flex-container" class="container"></div>
        <h1 align="center">Grid</h1>
        <div id="grid-container" class="container"></div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that you are looking for CSS Media Queries, the technique which allows you to setup specific behavior on different conditions (i.e. resolutions). Check this article https://cssmine.com/ebook/css3-media-queries

Comment: Thank you @DenisO. for the quick reply. I am sorry for not being clear and thus updated the post. I have succeeded with media queries for specific screens, however it is difficult to set tens of media queries. I am looking for a more general solution.